# AJAX response div color modification

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I want to change background colors of divs when the AJAX response has a type of value (specifically = "BusyChair").

I have a picture in the background where I drew divs. I know there should be a better way, but this is what I'm came up with. So we have many more chairs, I just wanted to point out how it is working.

HTML + JS part + CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#roomName{
 width:8%;
 height:5%;
 background-color: #ddd;
 position:fixed;
 border: solid;
 left : /*position*/;
 top : /*position*/;
}

article {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
}

#chair01 {
 width:0.5%;
 height:0.5%;
 background-color: #ddd;
 position:fixed;
 border: solid;
 left : /*position*/;
 top : /*position*/;
}
#chair02 {
 width:0.5%;
 height:0.5%;
 background-color: #ddd;
 position:fixed;
 border: solid;
 left : /*position*/;
 top : /*position*/;
}
#chair03 {
 width:0.5%;
 height:0.5%;
 background-color: #ddd;
 position:fixed;
 border: solid;
 left : /*position*/;
 top : /*position*/;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav><!-- basic navbar --></nav>
<article>
    <div>
        <div id="roomName">ROOM NAME</div>
        <div id="chair01"></div>
        <div id="chair02"></div>
        <div id="chair03"></div>
        <img id='background'>
    </div>
</article>
<script src="useful/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var locations;
var date_times;
var i;
var text ='';
setInterval(() => {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'PHP/chair_stat.php',
      success: function(data,result) {
        $.each(data,function(key,item){
            locations = item.Location;
            date_times = item.Date_Time;
            if(locations.includes('chair01')){
                document.getElementById('chair01').style.backgroundColor="#00d61d";
            }
        });
        }
    });
  }, 1000);
</script>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('background').src='Resources/Pictures/MainBuilding/AllRooms.PNG';
    document.getElementById('background').style.width ='98%' 
    document.getElementById('background').style.border ='solid';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require ('connect_to_db.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM actual_location_status WHERE Status='BusyChair' ORDER BY Date_Time";
$sql_param = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT parameter_data FROM all_parameters WHERE name_of_parameter = 'Normal_Busy_Time'");
$row_param = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_param);

$time_left;
$time_left = $row_param[0];




$result = $conn->query($sql);
$gathered = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $gathered[] =$row;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($gathered);

 ?>
```

What should happen.

1. View the page with all the chairs on it. (with greyish background color).
2. Asking data every second and if a chair gets busy, must recolor the background color to green.
3. There is a "Normal_Busy_Time" which is 01:30:00 (H-m-s) and a "Time_When_Gets_Busy" for ex.:2021-02-16 11:45:30. When the Time_When_Gets_Busy + Normal_Busy_Time passes I need to recolor the background of the div to red. I didn't even got so far, because the first two part is got me stuck.

I don't need a complete solution, I just need a path to go along with.

Questions:

- Do I use the AJAX response correctly? (I mean I get a JSON obj which I parse to a string).
- Was this approach any good? (I mean my mind is already bugging me about this solution is garbage)
- Ideas are welcomed, I can restart this from scratch. (Especially if there is an approach that make my code look at least a little bit cleaner). Keep in mind there are 80 chairs in a Room and 4 rooms I have to take care of.

Comment: Hi, so what doesn't work here ?

Comment: The code part is working, its just feels odd. Like I don't know how to progress towards, the coloring of the other divs. Let's say the response will get me 78 unique chairs. How do I color the reamining 77 without writing if_else-if_else's everywhere?

Comment: can you show output of json ?

Comment: 0: Object { Loc: "CH01",  Stat: "BusyChair", Date_Time: "2021-02-16 10:45:30", … }
​
1: Object { Loc: "CH02",  Stat: "BusyChair", Date_Time: "2021-02-16 10:45:30", … }

Comment: So here `Loc` is used to identify which element to color and that value matches with id of element ?

Comment: Yes!
So let's say, the response gave me CH01 , CH02 which i need to color. But my type of approach was very "code first ask questions later"... which is not good I know.

Comment: Not to worry atleast you tried something that's a good start . One more question :  how that divs get generated ? can you show that code as well ?

Comment: The divs are hardcoded, all of them by id like so:
        <div id="roomName"><b>RoomName 01-03</b></div>
        <div id="ch01" ></div>
        <div id="ch02"></div>
        <div id="ch03"></div>
And so on and so forth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As value of `Loc` and your `id` are same you can directly target that inside your `each` loop using `$("div[data-id=" + locations.toLowerCase() + "]")` and then background color of that div . Also, use `data-id` instead of id and generate those divs using `for-loop`  .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose data look like this
var data = [{
    Loc: "CH01",
    Stat: "BusyChair",
    Date_Time: "2021-02-16 10:45:30"
  },
  {
    Loc: "CH03",
    Stat: "BusyChair",
    Date_Time: "2021-02-16 10:45:30"
  }
]
$.each(data, function(key, item) {
  locations = item.Loc;
  $("div[data-id=" + locations.toLowerCase() + "]").css("background-color", "yellow"); //change bg color where data-id matches
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <div id="roomName"><b>RoomName 01-03</b></div>
  <div data-id="ch01">1</div>
  <div data-id="ch02">2</div>
  <div data-id="ch03">3</div>
</article>
```